# How can I change the color on a detail disclosure accessory in Swift?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, colors

I found some answers to this question for Objective-C, but I couldn't find much for Swift. I tried to take what I found and make it work for Swift, but I'm running into a problem: When I added the line `self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()` the background is as it should be, but the color of the arrow doesn't change when it's highlighted. When that line of code is commented out, the arrow color changes like it should but the background is black (and I want it clear). Here is what I have so far for the class...

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomColoredAccessory: UIControl {
    var accessoryColor: UIColor = .lightGrayColor()
    var highlightedColor: UIColor = .whiteColor()

    init(accessoryColor: UIColor, highlightedColor: UIColor) {
        super.init()
        self.accessoryColor = accessoryColor
        self.highlightedColor = highlightedColor
        CGRectMake(0, 0, 11.0, 15.0)
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        let myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 11.0, 15.0)
        super.init(frame: myFrame)
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()    // This is the line mentioned above
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // (x,y) is the tip of the arrow
        let x = CGRectGetMaxX(self.bounds)-3.0
        let y = CGRectGetMidY(self.bounds)
        let R: CGFloat = 4.5
        var ctxt = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctxt, x-R, y-R)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, x, y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctxt, x-R, y+R)
        CGContextSetLineCap(ctxt, kCGLineCapSquare)
        CGContextSetLineJoin(ctxt, kCGLineJoinMiter)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(ctxt, 3)

        if (self.highlighted) {
            self.highlightedColor .setStroke()
        } else {
            self.accessoryColor .setStroke()
        }

        CGContextStrokePath(ctxt)
    }

}
```

and I'm implementing it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath tableView method with the following lines:

```
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Text"

    let accessory: CustomColoredAccessory = CustomColoredAccessory(accessoryColor: UIColor.blackColor(), highlightedColor: UIColor.whiteColor())
    cell.accessoryView = accessory

    return cell
```

I'm also pretty sure my init methods aren't kosher, but I sort of just threw things at the wall until they stuck. Any insight would be appreciated!